# How to access image files from within executable that is called by hadoop mapper

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hadoop

I have some opencv function written in C++ and its compiled as binary in linux. This function takes image file location as source and processes it and gives a value as output.

Now, I am using hadoop streaming that has mapper written in python which calls this binary to process an image. Input to the mapper is a text file where each line has image file path.

**So far:**

First I tested the streaming mapreduce with a system call instead of calling img processing exe and all works as expected.
I have made all libraries needed for the binary such as opencv libraries etc. 
I tested my mapreduce by giving empty file location to the image processing binary. It works as its supposed to and gives my embedded error msg within the binary as output. It successfully completes all map and reduce and gives output.

**Issues and Questions:**

But when I give an actual image location to the binary. Mapreduce fails saying 
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA

Any ideas on how to give file location to the binary? Or should I read the image in the mapper and send the image data as binary to the called exe?

Comment: Are the file paths HDFS paths, or local file paths?

Comment: I tried both.. neither of them worked.

Comment: In MapReduce, your local files may not exist on the machine your Map task runs on, unless it is in some shared drive.  You would have to alter your C++ executable to be able to read from HDFS (using libhdfs) if you want to use them.

Comment: @MattD, two follow up questions:  1. Is it possible to read files from local directory. I know the data has to be moved to the nodes that is being worked on and will be overload. But just curious.  2. I looked up libhdfs, so If I use hdfsOpenFile and then hdfsRead, will it be read as binary? I am thinking about how this could be used in conjunction with imread function in opencv.

Comment: 1.  It is possible to read local files in MapReduce, just remember relative paths will evaluate from where MapReduce executes your code.  2. hdfsRead will read in bytes, and it is up to you to parse them as an image.